# How to query sorted/indexed columns in Impala

Tags: sorting, hadoop, indexing, impala

I have to make a POC with Hadoop for a database using interactive query (~300To log database). **I'm trying Impala but i didn't find any solution to use sorted or indexed data**. I'm a newbie so i don't even know if it is possible.

**How to query sorted/indexed columns in Impala ?**

By the way, here is my table's code (simplified).
I would like to have a fast access  on the "*column_to_sort*" below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable (
 unique_id STRING,
 column_to_sort INT,
 content STRING
 )
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\073' 
 STORED AS textfile;
```

Comment: More info : whether i sort/index/bucket tables or not in hive, the Impala queries on this table read the same amount of Bytes. I don't find an other way to use sort.

Comment: My guesses for solutions : Instead of sorting the data, i could hash and partition _column_to_sort_ -- Or -- Use a compression format which can index data